A home server template to securely access personal apps
I have built a Node.js program called serverserver, and it creates a server that you can access remotely on your phone. When you start the program, it prompts you to visit your public IP address. You visit this on your phone, and the server prompts you to accept or deny this new user. Once you accept, the phone asks you to create a PIN number. Afterwards, you have access to your Node.js program.
After creating a pin, three cookies are stored in your browser. One is simply a session cookie that prompts for pin verification after an hour.
The other cookies are both SHA256 hashes. The secret cookie, along with the user's PIN, is stored in a file called user[n].secret on the server. The encrypt cookie is stored on the user's browser. It encrypts and decrypts that user's .secret file whenever the session cookie expires. When the user verifies their pin, both cookies are replaced with new hashes. This session authentication is checked every 5 seconds, and it’s a bit complex:
async function checkSessionAuth(req, res, next) {
    const clientSecretHash = req.cookies.secret;
    const clientEncryptHash = req.cookies.encrypt;
    
    const files = getSecretFiles();
    const currentFileCount = files.length;
    
    res.cookie('secret_count', currentFileCount.toString(), { 
        secure: true, 
        sameSite: 'lax', 
        maxAge: 3600000 
    });

    if (files.length === 0) {
        return next();
    }

    if (clientSecretHash && clientEncryptHash) {
        let fileFound = false;
        for (const file of files) {
            try {
                const encryptedContent = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
                const decryptedContent = decryptData(encryptedContent, clientEncryptHash);
                const [storedHash, pin] = decryptedContent.split('\n');
                
                if (storedHash === clientSecretHash) {
                    fileFound = true;
                    if (pin && !req.cookies.pin_verified) {
                        return res.redirect('/pin');
                    }
                    return next(); 
                }
            } catch (error) {
                // Continue to next file if decryption fails
            }
        }

        if (!fileFound) {
            for (const cookieName in req.cookies) {
                res.clearCookie(cookieName);
            }
            return res.status(403).send('Access Denied');
        }
    }

    return res.redirect('/main');
}

I have built a few apps, including a photo cloud app called pikamp, that use secureserver. Links are on the GitHub page.
https://github.com/BTCapsule/secureserver

Sounds like you could use a VPN instead. WireGuard is easy to set up. Implementing security is hard. It's fine to do it for testing and learning, but to have it as the sole line of defense is a bit sketchy.

Building your own security is a bad idea (unless it is a learning exercise). Instead, use something that already exists.


it’s a bit complex

Indeed.
What the OP submission is missing is a description of the Use Case
and the Invariants which the code promises to preserve.
We're defending against an attacker Mallory who is motivated to
compromise this protocol, given that there's a bitcoin wallet behind it.
Mallory might be at several positions in the network,
including running a transparent proxy, or having possession
of your unlocked phone. None of the comments or Review Context
discuss how powerful the attacker is and what (finite) security
parameters the business problem is willing to accept.
Without writing down such assumptions, it becomes impossible
to assess whether the implemented code satisfies stated requirements.
I recommend that you produce such a document.
comments
The only hint we're given about
the contract
is that the function is named checkSessionAuth.
There are some business use cases where that might be an adequate
amount of documentation, but not here, not if you're defending a wallet.
We need to see a reference to your design document,
or see the assumptions and promises clearly spelled out
at the top of the function.
extract helper
The fileFound flag is at the heart of this function,
and it increases the complexity of what we need to reason about,
the things we must keep juggling in the back of our mind.
Take the opportunity to extract that for loop to a
separate function that has its own (much simpler!) promises to keep.
security parameter
Your system permits an attacker to send a new attempt every nine seconds.
Let's call it ten seconds.
The PIN entropy is limited to a set of \$10,000\$ numbers.
A day has a little more than \$10^5\$ seconds in it.
Maybe all this is a good match for your business needs,
but I'm skeptical.
cryptographic primitive
It's unclear why we are encrypting bits when in some places
it would suffice to hash
secret bits. If a challenge nonce or a server-supplied timestamp challenge
is part of your protocol, I'm afraid I didn't notice that.
binding credentials to client
We have some combination of high-entropy Local Secrets in filesystems,
plus four digits of a Thing That You Know,
and Mallory presumably is able to sniff a valid request
and attempt to replay it.
I didn't notice anything in the OP source code which binds
credentials to IP address;
we are apparently allowing Mallory to attempt replays from any host
without need of spoofing a source address.
And Mallory could attack from a pool of ten or more IP proxy servers.
You may wish to revisit the decision to let Mallory do such things.

You're designing a security protocol.
Proceed with caution.
You get to make the rules, you set the field upon which the
battle will be waged. Take care to tilt it in your favor.
